# ASP.NET MVC routing - adding sitename?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

So, I need for my website to have this being passed around in the routing:

blah.com/sitename/{controller}/{action}/{id}

The "sitename" is like a Vdir, but not quite. It will help me get the right data etc... for the given sitename.

What is the best way of doing this? I tried doing this in the routing but no go as it cannot find the page (this is when I am trying direct to the login page):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{sitename}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Users will be given a url like blah.com/somesite or blah.com/anothersite.

I just want the ability for routing to work as normal but be able to extract the "somesite" or "anothersite" portion around the controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a route to `Global.aspx.cs` to pass a `{sitename}` parameter:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Sites", // Route name
   "{sitename}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
   new { sitename = "", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }// Parameter defaults
);
```

Create a New Controller called `BaseController`. Then add the following simple code inside a base controller:

```
public class BaseController: Controller
{
   public string SiteName = "";

   protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       HttpRequestBase req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
       SiteName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["sitename"] as string;
       base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
   }
}
```

And use in your derived controller:

```
public class HomeController: BaseController
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       ViewData["SiteName"] = SiteName;
       return View();
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. yes, I found this/pretty much did it. Problem is for some reason sometimes when going to a particular "site" like... /somedevtraining/ - it fails but other variations/combinations works fine.